# Hide Properties Tab in Umbraco

Tags: html, angularjs, umbraco

I would like to hide default Properties tab in my DocumentType in Umbraco because i don't want some users to have access to this information.
Is that possible?

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Not possible, out of the box.

Comment: Depends on version, I think. For v4/6 there are packages like uHidesy that might help. But not for v7 (yet) :-/

Comment: Is attackmonkey package available on version 7? @JannikAnker

Comment: Don't think so, but you could check over on our.umbraco.org?

Comment: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/attackmonkey-tab-hider :-(

Comment: [This](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/developing-umbraco-7-packages/57017-Umbraco-7-Event-RemoveHide-tab-for-User-X) may be a starting point according to [Hideous1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2938741/hideous1).